# ¿Como usar botones en formulario HTML para elegir entre varias opciones?

Tags: html, css, html5, ionic, formularios

Estoy maquetando un formulario de registro y la sección de elección de sexo no está diseñada como un dropdown si no como tres botones que al elegir uno queda en activo y no se como realizar esto en HTML y CSS.

He intendado poner un type button pero no funciona, me sale un botón sin texto dentro y solo se puede hacer click sin resultados.

```
<div class="infoPersonal">
<form class="formPersonal">
    <span class="textForm">Nombre:</span><br>
    <input class="boxName" type="text" name="nombreForm"><br>
    <span class="textForm">Fecha de nacimiento:</span>
    <span class="textForm">Población:</span>
    <input class="boxDate" type="date" name="fechaForm">
    <input class="boxCity" type="text" name="cityForm"> 
    <span class="textForm">Sexo:</span>
    <input class="boxMujer" type="button" name="mujerForm" placeholder="Mujer">
</form>
```

Adjunto una imagen para que se entienda mejor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Gracias!

Comment: Bienvenida a stackoverflow en español, debes leer [ask] para que sepas como redactar una buena pregunta, debes agregar el código que has intentado usar y decirnos que problemas o errores tienes, también te invito a que te hagas el [tour] para que entiendas el funcionamiento básico del sitio y ganes tu primer medalla, saludos!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usando solo **HTML** y **CSS** podrías hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```css
.formPersonal span{
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.formPersonal .labelsex{
  padding: 6px 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
}

.boxSexo:checked + label{
  background: purple;
  color: white;
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.boxSexo{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="infoPersonal">
  <form class="formPersonal">
      <span class="textForm">Sexo:</span>
      
      <input class="boxSexo" type="radio" name="sexo" value="Mujer" id="mujerForm">
      <label class="labelsex activo" for="mujerForm">Mujer</label>
      
      <input class="boxSexo" type="radio" name="sexo" value="Hombre" id="hombreForm">
      <label class="labelsex" for="hombreForm">Hombre</label>
      
      <input class="boxSexo" type="radio" name="sexo" value="Otros" id="otrosForm">
      <label class="labelsex" for="otrosForm">Otros</label>   
  </form>
</div>
```

Lo que estamos haciendo es por medio de **CSS** seleccionar el elemento que esté inmediatamente después del `input` checkeado y asignándole un estilo diferente al resto para dar la sensación de que está "activo".

Si tienes alguna pregunta no dudes en hacerla.

Comment: Muchas gracias!! Funciona perfectamente!  :)

Comment: @Alba, no te olvides de marcar la respuesta como correcta asi se da la pregunta como solucionada y facilita a otros que tengan la misma duda a encontrar una respuesta mas rápido.

Comment: @Alba me alegra que te sirviera, considera marcar la respuesta como aceptada para que sea de ayuda a otros desarrolladores, recuerda hacer el [tour], saludos

Comment: Hecho! Me estoy familiarizando con la web..!

Comment: @Alba genial, por eso he sido tan "repetitivo" con el tema de que hagas el [tour], allí podrás entender como funciona el sitio, saludos !

Answer (score 2):

Te invito a estudiar un poco más sobre los [elementos de formulario en html](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp) y explorar cada uno de los distintos tipos y sus usos.

Si bien no existe una opción que automaticamente te permita darle el estilo que quieres, de forma nativa, si hay formas de simularlos, por ejemplo el elemento que buscas por ejemplo es el `input` de **"botones radiales"** o `radio` en inglés. Estos permiten asociar una pregunta con múltiple respuesta, donde solo puede haber una única respuesta a diferencia del tipo **"check"** que permite seleccionar más de una respuesta.

```html
<h5>Inputs radio</h5>

<input name="asociacion" type="radio">
<input name="asociacion" type="radio">
<input name="asociacion" type="radio">
<input name="asociacion" type="radio">

<h5>Inputs Checkbox</h5>

<input name="asociacion" type="checkbox">
<input name="asociacion" type="checkbox">
<input name="asociacion" type="checkbox">
<input name="asociacion" type="checkbox">
```

**La relación y/o agrupación entre los distintos inputs**, se hace mediante el atributo `"name"` como puedes ver en el ejemplo anterior.

Una vez entendido esto, debes entender que hay una relación directa entre los elementos label y los inputs, estos se correlacionan mediante el atributo `for` en el caso de los `label` y el atributo `id` para los `inputs`.

```css
label{
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
}

label:hover{
  background: gray;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form>

<h5>Inputs radio</h5>

<input name="asociacion" type="radio" id="input_1">
<input name="asociacion" type="radio" id="input_2">
<input name="asociacion" type="radio" id="input_3">

</form>
<br><br>
<div>
  <label for="input_1">Input 1</label>
  <label for="input_2">Input 2</label>
  <label for="input_3">Input 3</label>
</div>
```

Ya el resto vendría a ser la magia de css, **para esto oculta los inputs radio y haz solo visible los label**. Como ves no importa si no están lado a lado los inputs o labels, pueden estar separados o incluso anidados, van a seguir relacionados. **Ahora si queremos que el estilo de los label parezca como si los hubiésemos checkeado** (como en la imagen que nos compartes), el orden si es importante, ya que la única forma de relacionarlos vía CSS, es cumpliendo las siguientes condiciones:

1. Los inputs y los label, no pueden estar anidados en elementos html diferentes.
2. Los inputs deberían no anidados, arriba de toda la estructura.
3. Si los labels están consiguientes a los inputs, podemos usar la siguiente sintaxis:

```
#input_1:checked ~ label[for="input_1"]{
  /*Estilos...*/
}
```

4. Si los label, están anidados en un elementos html, tienes que relacionar al padre y luego a los labels, algo así:

```
#input_1:checked ~ .padre_ancestro label[for="input_1"]{
  /*Estilos...*/
}
```

Un ejemplo todo junto sería, algo así:

```css
.pregunta{
  padding: 1em;
}

input.esconder{
  position: fixed;
  opacity: 0;
}

/*Esto es para crear una excepción en el label que tenga la clase group*/ 
/*Podría haber colocado los estilos del 3er ejemplo aquí, pero para que no te confundas, los separe más abajo*/
label:not(.grupo){
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3em;
}

label:not(.grupo):hover{
  background: gray;
  color: white;
}

/*Estilos para estructura 1*/
#input_1:checked ~ div label[for="input_1"],
#input_2:checked ~ div label[for="input_2"],
#input_3:checked ~ div label[for="input_3"],
/*Estilos para estructura 2*/
#input_4:checked + label[for="input_4"],
#input_5:checked + label[for="input_5"]{
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

/*Estilos para estructura 3*/
label.grupo span{
  display: inline-button;
  background: whitesmoke;
  padding: 0.5em 1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 3em;
}

label.grupo:hover span{
  background: gray;
  color: white;
}

#input_6:checked + span,
#input_7:checked + span{
  background: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<form>
    
    <fieldset class="pregunta uno">

    <legend>Estructura 1</legend>

      <input name="asociacion" type="radio" id="input_1" class="esconder">
      <input name="asociacion" type="radio" id="input_2" class="esconder">
      <input name="asociacion" type="radio" id="input_3" class="esconder">

      <div>
        <label for="input_1">Input 1</label>
        <label for="input_2">Input 2</label>
        <label for="input_3">Input 3</label>
      </div>
      
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="pregunta dos">

    <legend>Estructura 2</legend>

      <input name="asociacion" type="radio" id="input_4" class="esconder">
      <label for="input_4">Input 4</label>

      <input name="asociacion" type="radio" id="input_5" class="esconder">
      <label for="input_5">Input 5</label>
      
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="pregunta tres">

    <!--Esta 3ra estructura es para anidar o agrupar tanto el label como el input, en este caso el estilo que simula ser un botón se lo aplicamos al <span> que contendrá el <label> y que deberá estar consiguiente del <input type="radio">-->

    <legend>Estructura 3</legend>

    <label for="input_6" class="grupo">
      <input name="asociacion" type="radio" id="input_6" class="esconder">
      <span>Input 6</span>
    </label>
    
    <label for="input_7" class="grupo">
      <input name="asociacion" type="radio" id="input_7" class="esconder">
      <span>Input 7</span>
    </label>
      
    </fieldset>

</form>
```

Si tienes otra pregunta, dejame tu comentario. Éxitos!

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta!!  :)

Comment: De nada! :) Revisa otra vez, actualicé un poco más la respuesta para hacerla más completa, pero igual me demore mucho redactando y veo que ya te respondieron, igual dice lo mismo, pero en una forma majestuosamente más breve. Éxitos!